# IntelliJ IDEA - GIT

Tags: git, intellij-idea

Hei, 
I have a doubt. 
I am executing a JavaScript-React project. I followed these steps:

-I cloned the project from GIT into my computer
-I compiled the project successfully (it is running successfully in the browser)
-I open the project with Intellij IDEA

Until here everything is fine, but I can see that IntelliJ IDEA is able to see the remote and local branches. My question is?

How can IntelliJ IDEA know about the remote branches if I never provide the GIT URL? How is it able to create the link by just opening the project?  Maybe my question is very simple, but I am bit confused....

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you cloned your project, and perhaps this is the ultimate source of confusion.  When doing a `git clone` from the command line, you would execute something like this:

```
git clone https://github.com/YOUR-USERNAME/YOUR-REPOSITORY
```

That is, to clone you would need to have knowledge of the remote Git repository's URL.  So, IntelliJ's Git plugin, which sits on top of Git, would "know" about the remote URL.  But, it would not even need to talk to the remote to have visibility to the remote *tracking* branches of your repository.  When you clone, you pull in these remote tracking branches, which exist *locally* in your system.

The key point here is that the "remote" branches to which you are referring actually exist locally, and in fact they come in at the time you clone.  They are updated whenever you do a `git fetch`.

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ IDEA knows about remote branches because underlying Git repository knows about them.

- Use command `git branch --remotes` to check the remote branches.
- Use `git remote --verbose` to check which remotes are recorded in the local repository.